# E5-2690 V2 on supermicro B9DR7 rev1.01?

Tags: xeon, supermicro

We bought bunch of E5-2690 before we check our board series.

Our board series is Supermicro B9DR7 rev1.01.
We tried to upgrade bios to version 3.
Have no luck, board can not be boot.

Kindly please give me any advise.

Sincerely

-bino-

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide answers to [well-asked questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). A part of asking a good question is doing some research before you ask, and letting us know what you already tried. Please update your question so that it shows that you put in some effort before posting your question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this FAQ entry on the SuperMicro website:](https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=17309)

> **Q:** Customer reported their new blade SBI-7427R-S3 (B9DR7) with CPU E5-2690 v2 does not post when booting up after Bios updated R3.0. What is going on?
>
> **A:** To support new processor v2 series, your blade B9DR7 must be **rev 1.02**.

Your blade is **rev 1.01** which according to SuperMicro is **not** compatible.